# Windows phone Post thread message, Post message

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Does WP support APIs like PostThreadMessage or PostMessage which were there in Windows Mobile earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, that type of API calls aren't available on Windows Phone!

In fact, you can't call any of the Win32 API calls we used in Windows Mobile; you are limited to what the managed SDK allows you to do!

Comment: Thats True, but are there any APIs exposed which do similar things. It would be good to have such APIs as a developer could create his seperate Message queues which could very useful.